# Is it possible to add some disk space to ubuntu installed drive?if then what is the way?

Tags: partitioning, disk, boot-partition

I have installed Ubuntu in a drive that has low disk space I need more space on that disk. How can I add more space to that disk?

[Gparted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdOoG.png)

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL            UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT

sda                                                                 
├─sda1 ntfs   System Reserved  6A60F08B60F05F6F                     
├─sda2 ntfs                    DE921B35921B119F                     
├─sda3 ntfs   Software & Study 04747C18747C0EA4                     
├─sda4                                                              
├─sda5 ntfs   Videos           E8B4589FB45871D4                     
├─sda6 ntfs   Audio & Natok    C616AD7C16AD6E5D                     
├─sda7 ntfs   SSSS             464C2B9B4C2B8531                     
├─sda8 swap                    ee80a977-2201-4144-b63a-53ac92557ab4 [SWAP]
└─sda9 ext4                    1d5eb22e-590d-4773-abb5-80906f0709d0 /
sr0
```

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           591M  9.1M  582M   2% /run
/dev/sda9        26G   21G  4.1G  84% /
tmpfs           2.9G   77M  2.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           591M   76K  591M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3       127G  110G   18G  87% /media/sazib/Software & Study
```

[GParted Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdOoG.png)

Comment: Paste the result of `lsblk -f` ...

Comment: I already add the result of lsblk -f

Comment: If you can edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, I can make a better recommendation. Show us the output of `df -h`. To get my attention, start new comments with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have already updated

Comment: **Without seeing the gparted image that I requested, I have no idea where you might have free space to allocate to Ubuntu.** The `df -h` command confirms that your disk is close to full right now, so I understand why you need to add space, but you may not have it.

Comment: @heynnema I have added gparted screenshot.

Comment: I've looked at your gparted image. I'm sorry to say that there's nothing extra there... your disk is full. You can only delete old stuff that you don't need any more, or get a bigger disk.

Comment: @heynnema If i delete some data from sda7 that is labeled as SSSS, is it possible to do something?

Comment: Yes, that would help.

Comment: @heynnema I have deleted some data from sda7 drive and updated the gparted screenshot.would you please check it again?

Comment: Please see my complete answer, below. Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After having deleted stuff from sda7, there's now room to increase the Ubuntu partition sda9.

## Backup any important data from Ubuntu first!

1. You'll need a Ubuntu Live DVD
2. Review the instructions for `Boot Repair` and print out the instructions for how to install it in the Ubuntu Live environment, and how to use it, just in case Ubuntu won't boot when you're done. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for detailed info

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

3. To start the process...

   - update: boot into Windows
   - update: **shrink** the sda7 partition, leaving some free space in the partition, using the `Disk Management` application
   - boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and start `gparted`
   - <strike>right-click on sda7, in the bottom window pane, choose move/**resize**, and in the graphic representation, hover the mouse pointer over the right side of sda7 and you'll see an arrow, then drag the right side of sda7 to the left (watching the numeric values shown below), leaving some spare space in the partition, then click OK</strike>
   - right-click on sda8, in the bottom window pane, and issue a `swapoff` command
   - right-click on sda8, in the bottom window pane, choose **move**/resize, and if you hover the mouse pointer over sda8 in the graphic representation, it'll turn into a hand cursor, then **move** the entire sda8 partition all the way to the left (the **size** of sda8 should not change), then click OK (**if you can't do this step, then STOP here, and let me know**)
   - right-click on sda9, in the bottom window pane, choose **move/resize**, and in the graphic representation, using the hand cursor, **move** the entire sda9 partition all the way to the left, then **resize** the right side of sda9 all the way to the right, then click OK
   - click the `Apply` icon to begin the work
   - right-click on sda8, in the bottom window pane, and issue a `swapon` command
   - reboot to Ubuntu

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.